# Java Thread Synchronization - placement of synchronized keyword

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to synchronize a thread application using the synchronized keyword. It acts weird at times. There is an ambiguity in placement of the keyword synchronized. The code is as follows :

```
class Athread implements Runnable
{
    public void run() {

            System.out.println("Starting Implementation of Class Athread");
            for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Class Athread :"+i);
            }
            System.out.println("Ending Implementation of class Athread");
    }
}

class Bthread implements Runnable
{
    public void run() {

            System.out.println("Starting Implementation of Class Bthread");
            for(int i=11;i<=20;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Class Bthread :"+i);
            }
            System.out.println("Ending Implementation of class Bthread");
    }
}

public class ThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Program starts..");

        Athread t1 = new Athread();
        Thread th1 = new Thread(t1);


        Bthread t2 = new Bthread();
        Thread th2 = new Thread(t2);

        synchronized(th1){
            th1.start();
        }
        synchronized(th2){
            th2.start();
        }

        System.out.println("Program ends...");
    }
}
```

When I place the synchronized block at the start of my thread it should lock that thread and not interleave with other threads. Sadly, the output is not as expected. My output is as follows :

```
Program starts..
Program ends...
Starting Implementation of Class Athread
Starting Implementation of Class Bthread
Class Athread :1
Class Bthread :11
Class Athread :2
Class Bthread :12
Class Athread :3
Class Bthread :13
Class Athread :4
Class Bthread :14
Class Athread :5
Class Bthread :15
Class Athread :6
Class Bthread :16
Class Athread :7
Class Bthread :17
Class Athread :8
Class Bthread :18
Class Athread :9
Class Bthread :19
Class Athread :10
Class Bthread :20
Ending Implementation of class Athread
Ending Implementation of class Bthread
```

Even when I use the synchronized keyword in the run() method of both the class I do not get the actual desired output.

Can anyone please explain me how synchronized keyword can be applied to my above example.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

In the question above I had wrongly understood the concept of synchronization. According to the comments received I am trying to call ***two different threads and access two different resources***.But synchronization should be done on a shared/common resource. Hence there should be a common location on which I should try synchronizing.

Comment: What do you think `synchronized` does?

Comment: It controls the access of a thread over other threads. In short it says,"only one thread at a time"

Comment: And what does it do to the argument you pass to it? And how does that relate to a different argument you pass to a different `synchronized` block?

Comment: The following statement from your qn is false:  "When I place the synchronized block at the start of my thread it should lock that thread and not interleave with other threads."  Putting synchronized around `th1.start()` only delays the next call to `th2.start()` briefly until the first `th1.start()` call has returned, *not* until the entire Athread `run()` method has executed.

Comment: i would suggest reading the synchronize java tutorial.

Comment: As I am passing a thread object, it locks that thread and allows that thread to complete its execution.

Comment: What does _locks thread_ mean? Lock it related to what? What is a `Thread`? You have a lot wrong. [Read this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Comment: make base solid and then start building

Comment: ...actually, I was wrong in my above comment.  Your two synchronized blocks will have absolutely no effect given that `main()` is only run on a single thread.  The issue is still the same though:  `th1.start()` returns immediately, not after Athread `run()` has completed, allowing `th2.start()` to kick in the Bthread `run()` method.

Comment: http://ideone.com/BQfmQd is the desired runtime behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is, you synchronized piece of code where your thread start. And at that time only main method is getting executed, so putting synchronized block you achieved nothing.

Second thing is you are creating 2 threads on 2 different object, so neither of threads interfering with each other, so putting synchronized block in run or synchronizing run method wont do anything different.

I dont know what exactly you want to achieve, but I modified your code for 'synchronized' example.

```
class MyClass implements Runnable{
    public void run() {
            System.out.println(this);
            System.out.println("Starting Implementation of "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            synchronized(this){
                for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
                    System.out.println("Class  :"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+i);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Ending Implementation of "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}


public class ThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Program starts..");

        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        Thread th1 = new Thread(obj);
        Thread th2 = new Thread(obj);
        th1.setName("Athread");
        th2.setName("BThread");
        th1.start();
        th2.start();

        System.out.println("Program ends...");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this code works either, since the "this" on which you synchronize is different for the two threads.  As a quick (slightly ugly) fix, synchronize on MyClass.class.

Comment: for both thread 'this' means same object. see line 'Thread th1 = new Thread(obj);' and 'Thread th2 = new Thread(obj);'

Comment: For one of them this is th1, for the other th2.

Comment: put this statement 'System.out.println(this);' inside run method. No matter if you put that inside synchronized block or not. Both thread will print same value. th1, th2 are threads, they are executing run method of same MyClass object.

Comment: You are correct - while scrolling around on my little tablet I mixed up your code and OP's.  My bad.  I thought you had created two MyClass objects like OP had ( more or less). Normally you don't run two of the exact same thing but in this example you can.

Comment: +1 for the 'System.out.println(this);' statement. Can you explain me why does a thread take the address of a class. Doesnt it have its own call stack ? Can put some light on how the memory allocation of threads with reference to the above example. It would be of great help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The "this" which is being synchronized on is not the Thread, it is the instance of MyClass.  Since both of your printing loops are exactly the same, @aniruddha cleverly realized that you only need instantiate a single MyClass, named obj, then runs it in two different threads.  This is what briefly confused me as well.  In most situations you would have multiple instances of MyClass and this solution would not work.

Comment: @Neal: The statement 'System.out.println(this);' just to show that both threads sharing same object. Basically when you create thread object, you need give it runnable interface implementation. In example, its MyClass object. You use 'synchronized' when multiple threads accessing same resources or same piece of code, you want to make sure that only one thread access that code at a time. You can also synchronized 'MyClass.class' or you can define one instance variable (not primitive) & put lock on that variable.

Comment: About memory Each Thread also a separate object, so it also occupy on heap. As per my example, three objects will be on heap viz th1, th2 & obj.

Answer (score 1):

synchronized is used to synchronize a piece of code, a critical area that you want only one thread to operate upon at a point of time. Eg, your Balance amount in a bank.

Now, first, you are creating threads of two different classes, no idea why you wana do that here.
Second, you are not using any resource in classes to synchronize on.

Third, please use synchronize, inside the class who's Thread you are creating.

Comment: Can you please explain me with an example. It would be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that sure if its the right way of putting the synchronized block in the run() method usually synchronized is declared in a user defined method for ex.business method..

and also why are using the same variable 'i' in your loops? may it also cause some problem regards of increment-ing of values..

Comment: `i` is a local variable that is not visible outside of the `run` method - that part is entirely safe because the two `i` are different ones.

Answer (score 0):

if by desired output you mean that `Athread` shoudl finish before `Bthread` starts then your choice of synchronization is wrong.

Synchronize has 2 thinsg to understand:

1. threads block each other if the synchronize on same object
2. threads running in synchronized block on different objects dont block each other.

Now in your code you are putting synchronized around the calls to start method. So in effect each of the start method call is synchronized. But what you need is a mechanism to synchroniz the run methods of your Athread and Bthread.

To fix that add a synchronized block in your run methods which synchronizes on the same object. an example is given below.

```
Object lockObject = new Object();

class Athread implements Runnable
{
    public void run() {
        synchronized(lockObject){
            System.out.println("Starting Implementation of Class Athread");
            for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Class Athread :"+i);
            }
            System.out.println("Ending Implementation of class Athread");
        }
    }
}

class Bthread implements Runnable
{
    public void run() {
        synchronized(lockObject){
            System.out.println("Starting Implementation of Class Bthread ");
            for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Class Bthread :"+i);
            }
            System.out.println("Ending Implementation of class Bthread ");
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of `synchronized(lockObject)` you can also use `synchronized(ThreadDemo.class)`. The idea is that bpoth synchronized blocks should synchronize on the same object. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

`synchronized(foo) {  do stuff }` means that, while you are doing stuff, you have exclusive access to the object foo.  And you are willing to wait for it.  A good example might be a bank account.  While I am making a deposit to *my* bank account, nobody else may access it.  However, another thread is perfectly able to synchronize on, and access, *your* bank account, or my *savings* account.

In your example, you need a common object for both threads to "fight over".  One solution is to just create a third object, (non null!) of any kind.  Say a `static Object lockOnMe = new Object();`.

However, since you really want exclusive access to `System.out`, that would be a more logical choice.  While AThread or BThread is running, if they synchronize on System.out in their run() method, nobody else may access System.out and interfere with your nice output.

Now, in a "real" app there are drawbacks, as many threads might be stuck waiting to print, bu this works for a learning example.